# Python: while not Exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, while-loop

So I am aware you can use `try/except` blocks to manipulate the output of errors, like so:

```
try:
    print("ok")
    print(str.translate)
    print(str.foo)
except AttributeError:
    print("oops, found an error")

print("done")
```

...which gives the following output:

```
ok
<method 'translate' of 'str' objects>
oops, found an error
done
```

Now, is there a way to do the following with a `while` loop, like `while not AttributeError`, like this:

```
while not AttributeError:
    print("ok")
    print(str.translate)
    print(str.foo)
print("done")
```

which would give the same output as above, just without `oops, found an error`? This would reduce the need for `except: pass` type blocks, which are necessary but a little pointless if you have nothing to do in the `except` block.

I tried `while not AttributeError` and `while not AttributeError()`, which both just completely skip anything in the `while` block. So, is there a way to do this in Python?

**Edit:** This really isn't a *loop* per se, but the while block would run, and continue on if it encounters an error, and just continue on if it reaches the end.

Comment: You must see `try` / `except` blocks as "_if everything is ok_" / "_else_". Python raise all errors, if you want to "skip" one, `except AttributeError: pass` is the way to go. It's not pointless, you are explicitly saying you want to let this error pass (or apply another process, or whatever). EDIT: And, no there is not `while not AttributeError`

Comment: If there’s no exception raised, would it repeat anything?

Comment: @DavisHerring No, it would run the block until the end, and it would continue on regardless if there was an error or not. If there was an error, it would end early and just continue on.

Comment: Is this an infinite loop? What is the stopping condition? Does it break when an exception is encountered?

Comment: This is not how Exceptions should be utilised - please use the standard `try/except` methodology.

Comment: Aside from the fact that `while` *not* looping is… surprising, this new syntax would save just the **one line** `except AttributeError: pass`!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can you try something like:

```
while True:
    try:
        print("ok")
        print(str.translate)
        print(str.foo)
    except:
        break
print('done')
```

Answer (score 5):

The following code will loop until it encounters an error.

```
while True:
  try:
    print("ok")
    print(str.translate)
    print(str.foo)
  except AttributeError:
    print("oops, found an error")
    break
  print("done")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`suppress()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress) as an alternative to `try/except/pass` available for python 3.4+

```
from contextlib import suppress

while True:
    with suppress(AttributeError):
        print("ok")
        print(str.translate)
        print(str.foo)
    break
print('done')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can nest while loop:

```
try:
    while True:
        print("ok")
        print(str.translate)
        print(str.foo)
except AttributeError:
    print('done')
```

In this case you don't need to call `break` explicitly.